# Inclusion/Exclusion for at least x in n question

Tags: java, probability

I need to solve a probability question where someone invited n guests to his birthdayparty. I am given an integer x and a list with n entries. Every ith entry is giving the probability that guest i will  come to the party.

the question is to find the probability that at least x guests will be at the party.
i know there are several different better algorithms for this question but i wondered if i can solve this with the exclusion/inclusion principle.

i tried doing it like this:
-create all subsets of the quest probability list with at least x elements;
-then for every subset multiply the probabilities together, which should give the probability that at least those guests in the subset will be at the party.

-add the values of the subsets with cardinality x or x+k*2;
-substract values of the subsets with cardinality x+1 +k*2;

this doesn't work in the end because i get values much higher than 1 or -1. what am i doing wrong here?

can the principle of exclusion/inclusion only be used if we start with the most basic subsets with at least 1 element?

```
    int x = 5;

    double[] guests = new double[] {0.34, 0.24, 0.72, 0.28, 0.55, 0.88, 0.91, 0.0.99, 0.01, 0.46};
    
    ArrayList<Double> subset = new ArrayList<Double>();
    ArrayList<ArrayList<Double>> Subsets = new ArrayList<>();
    getSubsets(subset,Subsets,0,guests,x);
    
    double probx = 0;
    
    for(int i = 0;i<Subsets.size();i++){
      double prob = 1;
      for(int j = 0;j<Subsets.get(i).size();j++){
        prob = Subsets.get(i).get(j)*prob;
      }
     
      if((Subsets.get(i).size()%x)%2==0){
          
        probx += prob;
      }else{
          
        probx -= prob;
      }
    }
    
    System.out.println(probx);
}
public static void getSubsets(ArrayList<Double> tmp, ArrayList<ArrayList<Double>> subsets, int i, double[] guests, int maxlength) {
  if(i==tage.length) {
    if(tmp.size()>=maxlength) {
      subsets.add(tmp);
    }
    return;
  }
  ArrayList<Double> newSet = new ArrayList<>(tmp);
  newSet.add(guests[i]);

  getSubsets(newSet,subsets,i+1,guests,maxlength);
  getSubsets(tmp,subsets,i+1,guests,maxlength);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You could likely to solve this with Mote Carlo simulation. You have  n-variate Bernoulli distribution, but each Bernoulli sample is independent, so

- set count to 0
- simulate n-dim {0,1} vector using Bernoulli with probability p<sub>i</sub>
- sum vector, and if sum is >= x, then increment count
- repeat simulation N times, answer would be count/N

Don't know much of a Java, could write something in Python. Ping me if you need the code